# Bootstrap Navbar not lining up with eachother

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So, i have a bootstrap navbar with items in it, but for some reason they don't line up with the first item.

Screenshot:https://ibb.co/vvRh3Jf

You see how the items at the right aren't really lined with with the logo and the image.

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img class="ms-3" src="/static/img/AdiAvi.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      AdiAvi
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a {% if homePage %} class="nav-link active" {% endif %} {% if dashboardPage %} class="nav-link active" {% endif %} class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a {% if contactPage %} class="nav-link active" {% endif %} class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        {% if baseTemplate %}
        <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="ms-2 btn btn-danger navbar-btn">
          Login
      </button>
        {% endif %}
        {% if baseTemplate %}
        <button type="button" id="registerTrigger" class="ms-2 me-2 btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
            Register
        </button>
        {% endif %}
        {% if name %}
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="/static/profilePictures/A.png" width="50" height="50" class="rounded-circle mt-8">
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/account">Edit Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        {% endif %}   
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.rounded-circle {
    border-radius: 24px;
}
.mt-8  {
  margin-top: -8!important;
}
```

I tried giving all the atributes the class ms-3, because i gave the logo that class and it lined up like that, so i was guessing that would be the right thing to do, but nothing really happened at all. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You could also utilize the bootstrap classes (`d-flex`, `justify-content-center`, `align-items-center`).

```
.nav-item {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```